# Android: setText from button, where button text is given by string

Tags: java, android, string, button, settext

I've just started out with android (and java, yes I am learning the two simultaneously). As a basic project to develop skills I've been trying to write code for a calculator.

The keypad is formed of buttons, I have opted to put text on these through use of strings (I have read this is good practice to use strings over hard coded text).
Then, when the buttons are 'clicked' they append/setText of a TypeView item (as a calculator should!)

The use of strings is causing me problems.

If I had hard coded the text on buttons, I could use this:

```
//this part for initial reading as 0 and for disp usage later
TextView disp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
    disp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    disp.setText("0");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}
static boolean isempty=(true);
public void onClick(View btn)
{
    Button bt = (Button)btn;
    if (disp.getText().length()>7) return;
    if (isempty)
      {
        disp.setText(bt.getText());
        isempty=false;
      }
    else
      {
         disp.append(bt.getText());
      }
}
```

in order to write the text to screen.

Yes, it has much work, I know. Please could someone shed light on how to append/setText from strings? (ie how to modify the disp.append/disp.setText parts

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So what happening in your case?

Comment: The question isn't really clear -- regardless of how you're setting text (hardcoded vs. string resource), the way you get get/setText is the same. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You have to use string builder or string buffer for appending string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a file called string.xml in res/values.

The file should have the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Now to access that string, on your code you do:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Now you can set that string to your buttons.

Next, in your code you have to set the click listener to the buttons in your calculator, the TextView shouldn't be handling any events in this case. Your event for each button would be declared like this:

```
     btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Button btn = (Button) v;
             disp.append(btn.getText());
         }
     });
```

On your operator buttons for adding, substracting, etc. you need the event listeners to look like this:

```
     btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // handle the adding                
         }
     });
```

Comment: You can use @string/hello in Design's text field.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the if/else statement and add

```
String newText = disp.getText().toString() + bt.getText().toString();
disp.setText(newText);
isempty = newText.isEmpty();
```

But i am not sure to understand why your previous code is not ok.

EDIT (see comments)

```
disp.append(bt.getText());
isempty = true;
```

Comment: `newText` never be empty as every Button has a Text.

Comment: why should it be empty? When you click on a button you expect to add 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9 to the existing string. You don't want to add an empty text, right? Do I miss something ?

Comment: Means `isempty` is always remain **false**.

Comment: Yes, except if you don't click on any button. I thought the variable was tracking whether your textview is empty or not. If that is not the case, I am sorry. But what is the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I don't have a any problem. I just want to solve OP's problem. :) By the way the code written by OP is in Button's onClick() so always button text will be append to `newText`.

Comment: oh yes right!. Let's edit that :). is OP's problem really a problem ^^ ?